# linear stability analysis using spectral radius

Tags: ode, eigenvalues, finite-volume, stability

I am analysing the stability of a series of 1D linear equations of the form 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} x = A x
\end{equation} 
discretised using upwind and central finite volume methods, etc, with the explicit Euler time stepping scheme (to begin with).

What I have done so far is that I have calculated the eigenvalues of the system, and then plotted them. I then plotted a circle in the imaginary plane that contains all the eigenvalues, using the maximum and minimum eigenvalues. To comment on stability I then look at the radius of this circle and if it was less than one I concluded that stability is obtained.

I would be grateful if some could tell me if I am doing the right thing here, I have been through lots of books, etc and I got to this stage, but have not found something online or in books that verifies what I'm doing. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvalues of $A$ will only tell you something about the stability of the *continuous system* (and here you will need that the real parts of all eigenvalues are less than zero, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory#Linear_autonomous_systems)).
To analyse the stability of the system discretised with forward Euler, you will have to look not only at the eigenvalues of $A$, but of $I + \Delta t A$.

Using forward Euler, your time stepping becomes
\begin{equation}
u_{n+1} = u_{n} + \Delta t A u_{n} = \left( I + \Delta t A \right) u_{n}.
\end{equation}
Since you are looking at the spectral radius, let $A = U D U^{-1}$ be the eigenvalue decomposition of $A$. Then
\begin{equation}
u_{n+1} = u_n + \Delta t U D U^{-1} u_n \Rightarrow U^{-1} u_{n+1} = U^{-1} u_n + D U^{-1} u_n.
\end{equation}
Denote as $v := U^{-1} u$ your solution in transformed coordinates which satisfies
\begin{equation}
  v_{n+1} = v_{n} + \Delta t D v_n \Rightarrow v_{n+1} = \left( I + \Delta t D \right)^{n+1} v_0
\end{equation}
with $v_0 = U^{-1} u_0$ and $u_0$ your given initial solution. Since $D$ is a diagonal matrix, this corresponds to a set of scalar equations
\begin{equation}
v_{n+1}^{i} = ( 1 + \Delta t \lambda_{i} ) v_{0}^{i},
\end{equation}
where $v_{n+1}^{i}$ is the $i$-th component of $v$. Growth in terms of e.g. the maximum norm of $v$ can now be computed component wise since
\begin{equation}
\left| v_{n+1}^{i} \right| = \left| 1 + \Delta t \lambda_{i} \right| \left| v_{0}^{i} \right|.
\end{equation}
So if you want to ensure stability in the sense that $\left\| u_{n+1} \right\| \leq \left\| u_{0} \right\|$, you will have to make sure that
\begin{equation}
\left| 1 + \Delta t \lambda_{i} \right| \leq 1
\end{equation}
for every eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Thanks very much, I had totally missed  'I+ΔtA' rather than 'A'.
On a different note, I am using the ODE solvers in Matlab but also have used some other time stepping schemes, is it safe to say that if I performed the stability analysis using Explicit Euler time stepping schemes, that it more or less gives me the worst case scenario in terms of stability? (Or perhaps if I solve the problem with the different time stepping schemes, and show that Explicit Euler was the least stable i.e. it required smaller time steps to produce stable results?)

Comment: I would be careful with drawing conclusions from forward Euler about the stability of other methods: while some definitely have better stability properties, I don't think it is safe to consider explicit Euler as a worst case.

You can generalise the analysis above, though: Runge Kutta methods have what is called a stability function and, based on that, you can derive a similar condition to what I did above for forward Euler. You can read up on that e.g. in the following book (which gives in my opinion a very good introduction) http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780857291479